# Error in starting the neo4j Server (Neography, Ruby)

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neography

The server suddenly stopped to work and on restarting it gave the following error. Couldn't find anything related to this online. Any idea what is wrong and how to resolve this?

> org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log SEVERE: 
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed:
>   Active marked as 1 but no data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1 exist    at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:218)
>     at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)    at
>   org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Active marked as 1 but no
>   data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1 exist  at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLogFiles.determineState(XaLogicalLogFiles.java:138)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recoveryNeededAt(StoreRecoverer.java:65)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:56)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:333)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:152)
>     ... 2 more
>
> Apr 25, 2014 9:13:07 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log SEVERE:
>   Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've messed up your datastore e.g. by a unclean shutdown. To recover try the following procedure:

1. **IMPORTANT:** before doing any manual changes to your `graph.db` folder, make sure that you have a valid backup copy e.g. by `tar -zcf <path>/graph.db.tar.gz data/graph.db`.
2. Check that the backup from 1. is fine.
3. `rm data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.active`. NB: this operation might be harmful.
4. try to restart the server
5. if it comes up, check if the latest changes you did before the DB reached its current state.